# how to add a row in repeater using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how to add a row in repeater using jquery

my code is

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repChiefComplaint"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td class="frm_field_label_left">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbGuarentor1" runat="server" Text='' OnClientClick="return false;"></cube:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete1" runat="server" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='' SkinID="Delete" /></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***i want to add an Item in repeater***

As per comment

You wont be able to add anything to `ItemTemplate` using jQuery as repeater control is rendered using ASP.NET engine where as jQuery executes on client side.

You can add row `<tr></tr>` using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS selector syntax. It works if repeaters id begins from `rep`

```
var tr = '<ItemTemplate>
              <td class="frm_field_label_left">
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbGuarentor1" runat="server" Text="" OnClientClick="return false;"></cube:LinkButton>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete1" runat="server" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='' SkinID="Delete" />
              </td>
         </ItemTemplate>';   

$('[id*=rep]').append(tr)
```

Comment: It will add a table row but i want to add an Item in repeater not a row at the end of table

Comment: fixed it in answer. I just read in question what you need add row, not an item ))